# SSDT and Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, sql-server-data-tools

Using Visual Studio 2013, I'm trying to use a local development DB created by SSDT as the source for an Entity model.

I can connect to this DB using the Entity Data Model wizard, but non of the Tables, Stored Procedures, or Views show up.

According this article,http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/data-driver/2012/06/sql-server-data-tools-a-work-in-progress.aspx

"Also, integration with Entity Framework, which actually worked in the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview, was removed in the Visual Studio 11 Beta, as the SSDT blog explained in March. A post said: "Based on the feedback received and the remaining engineering work that would have been required to complete the experience, the decision was made to not include this functionality in Visual Studio 11."

Given this article is more than two years old, does anyone know if Microsoft added support for Entity in Visual Studio '13 SSDT?

Any other ideas as to why I cannot see any database objects?

Answer (score 0):

Have you published the database from visual studio to the local instance, right click on the DB proj and select publish.